# Comparing with boolean variable in C

Tags: c, c99, c11

Consider the code:

```
int foo(void)
{
    _Bool b = 1; // is true
    int i = 42;  // mean true in conditions

    if (i == b)
        return 1;
    else if ((_Bool)i == b)
        return 2;
    else
        return 3;
}
```

What will this function return according to the C standard (C99 or C11)?

P.S. On GCC 4.7.2 with `-std=c99` option the function returns 2.

Comment: You should see the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639136/integer-conversion-rank-of-signed-and-unsigned-int, and this link https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns `2`.

The "usual arithmetic conversions" are applied to the operands of the `==` operator. `_Bool` is an unsigned type with a conversion rank lower than that of `int` or `unsigned int`.

The "usual arithmetic conversions" are specified in section 6.3.1.8 "Usual arithmetic conversions" of either the [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) or [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) standard (the links are to recent drafts).

In `i == b`, since there are no floating-point operands, the "integer promotions" are applied to both operands, promoting the right operand from `_Bool` to `int` and yielding the value `1`. Now both operands are of the same type, so no further conversion is needed. So `i == b` is equivalent to `42 == 1`, which is false.

In `(_Bool)i == b`, the "integer promotions" are still applied to both operands, so both are converted from `_Bool` to `int`. (The conversion from `int` to `_Bool` and back to `int` loses information, converting all non-zero values to `1`.) Now both operands are of the same type, so no further conversion is needed. So `(_Bool)i == b` is equivalent to `1 == 1`, which is true -- and the function returns `2`.

(Note: Due to some carelessness on my part in reading the standard, this is about the third major edit of this answer. I think I've got it right this time.)

In answer to a question in the comments, `b == 42u` promotes `b` from `_Bool` to `int`, resulting in an `int` vs. `unsigned int` comparison. Since the operands have different signedness but the same conversion rank, the signed operand is converted to the unsigned type. Converting `1` from `int` to `unsigned int` is trivial, yielding `1u`. So the comparison is equivalent to `1u == 42u`, which is false.

(Note that the `==` operator in C, like the other equality and relational operators, yields a result of type `int` with the value `0` or `1`, *not* a result of type `_Bool`.)

Comment: `if(b == 42u)` is what TRUE or FALSE ? ...42 is suffixed with unsigned

Answer (score 0):

> If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are
>   performed.

As such, in evaluating the expression `i == b`, arithmetic conversion will occur. During arithmetic conversion, all involved operands are converted to the lowest ranked type that all can "fit" in, in this case `int`.

Since `1 != 42`, the first condition is not true.

The second expression first casts `i` to a `_Bool`, resulting in `true`. Then it evaluates `true == true` which is obviously `true`. Thus the function returns `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run it?

It is actually return `2`. gcc version 4.5.4 with `-std=gnu99`