# Opencv cv::waitKey() return value

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm debugging some C++ code that use OpenCV on Ubuntu 14, which is known to work On Ubuntu 12 and maybe with other OpenCV library build.

What was before

```
int key_pressed = waitKey(0);
cout << "key_pressed " << int(key_pressed) << endl;
switch( key_pressed )
{
    case 27: //esc
    {
        //close all windows and quit
        destroyAllWindows();
    }

    ...
```

But this code is not working and in output I have `key_pressed 1048603`

This code work:

```
char key_pressed = cv::waitKey();
cout << "key_pressed " << int(key_pressed) << endl;
switch( key_pressed )
{
    case 27: //esc
    {
        //close all windows and quit
        destroyAllWindows();
    }

    ...
```

This code is working and in output I have `key_pressed 27`

What can be reason of such behaviour?

P.S. [documentation says](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) that cv::waitKey() return `int`, so why we should convert it to `char`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function is highly dependent on the operating system :/ some of them add a bit to the integer....

it should return the ascii code of the key press, for example, `27` is the ascii code for the `ESC` key...

Now, the problem would be to know what happens when you cast an int to a `char`.

In this case: It is implementation-defined.... (That is what the standard says) here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294350/how-assignment-from-int-to-char-works-in-c) to a similar case

Some **solutions**:

1) put it into a char variable... even though it is implementation-defined it seems that is one of the most common working solutions (in some of the opencv samples they use it)

2) use `int key = cv::waitKey(1) & 255`. It will eliminate the extra bits...

To go a little bit further, lets check the values:

```
You obtained as an int: 1048603
in binary it will be: 00000000 00010000 00000000 00011011
27 in binary is:      00000000 00000000 00000000 00011011
```

As you can see they differ in that lone bit.... The safetest and most portable way is to remove it with a bitwise logic operation, such as my number 2 solution. Other people use some hex value instead of 255, such as 0xEFFFFF that in binary it will be

```
00000000 11101111 11111111 11111111
```

Why this happens?

I searched for this once, it seems that some of the bits changes if you have `numslock` or `capslock` or `ctrl` key active... again, this is platform dependent.