# How can an int be stored inside of a char, and how does it get printed using %d, not able to understand the following code?

Tags: c

code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
        
    char a = 1;
    char b = 2;
        
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
}
```

output:  1 2

Comment: @user3386109 Did you just remove the actual question?

Comment: @Erik You can look at the edit history. Just click the link above my name. In other words, "No."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How assignment from int to char works in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294350/how-assignment-from-int-to-char-works-in-c)

Comment: `printf()` is a function taking a variable number of arguments. For such functions, all `...` arguments undergo [default argument conversions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2). Specifically values of type `char` are converted to values of type `int` even before any code in the library runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `char` type is an integer type, similar to `short` or `int`. When you store characters in a `char` object, it actually stores a numeric code in the `char` object. For example, `x = 'b';` stores a code for “b” in `x`. (In implementations that use ASCII, the code for “b” is 98.) If you read a character from input and store it with `x = getchar();`, and the input is “b”, then the code for “b” is stored.

In many expressions in C, a `char` value is automatically promoted to an `int`. This includes when it is passed to `printf`. If you print the value using `%c`, `printf` prints the character represented by the value. If you print using `%d`, `printf` prints a decimal numeral for the value.

`char` may be a signed type, in which case it can represent values at least from −127 to +127. Or it may be unsigned, in which case it can represent values from 0 to at least 255.

Answer (score 1):

total number of Character in ASCII table is 256 (0 to 255), in C language each character represented using the integer value,
interesting  thing is that if you use %d the it will print the integer code for the character

```
  printf("%d", 'a'); /* output : 97 /*
```

but if you use %c the it will print the character

```
  printf("%c", 'a'); /* output : a */


  printf("%c", 97); /* output : a */

  char a=1 ;/* this a is not storing 1 but it is holding the ascii character 
  correspond to 1, this is due to implicit type casting done by compiler */
```

refer to this :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-c/

Comment: ASCII only defines codes from 0 to 127. The `char` type may hold other values, but those outside that use encodings beyond ASCII, and a C implementation might not use ASCII at all (the C standard permits other encodings, like EBCDIC). Additionally, `char` may be signed and limited to 127 on its high end.

Answer (score 0):

Chars will store integers in the range of -128 to 127 or from 0 to 255 depending if the char is signed or unsigned. The printf function arguments `a` and `b` are promoted to ints, and printed as ints as expected by the `%d` delimiter. With the delimiter `%c` they are still promoted to ints, but printed as characters.

Comment: The C standard only requires a signed `char` to hold values from −127 (not −128) to 127, and it permits more than those intervals for signed `char` and unsigned `char`.