# Using realloc() instead of fixed-length buffers in c?

Tags: c, memory-management, buffer, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I have some code that was written to be as conservative as possible with memory use, so it does things like use `realloc()`  for building strings a character at a time instead of a one-time fixed-length buffer as is commonplace. The advantage I see to this is you don't ever over-use memory in environments where that's important and you don't have to worry about the buffer being too small for corner cases and writing some `realloc()` code anyway to cover that. **My question is if this thrashes memory horribly or can cause any other problems, or if perhaps the compiler optimizes this away.**

Here is a sample program that reads a text file using no fixed-length buffers and it works fine. Why would you or would you not write code like this? Is it a patently bad idea?

```
// Compile with: gcc a.c -o a
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  void *tmp;
  char **array = NULL; // array of line strings
  size_t len = 0; // length of a line
  int i = 0; // line count

  // Open file
  FILE* f;
  if (!(f = fopen("./test.txt", "r"))) {
    printf("Err: open file\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // Read file into memory
  int chr;
  while ((chr = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    // Reserve mem for another line
    if (len == 0) {
      // add 2 -- 1 for null terminator, 1 cuz i starts at 0
      if ((tmp = realloc(array, (i+2)*sizeof(*array))) == NULL) {
        printf("Err: realloc\n");
        return 1;
      }
      array = tmp;
      array[i] = NULL;
      array[i+1] = NULL;
    }

    // Increase mem for next char in the line
    // add 2 -- 1 for null terminator, 1 cuz len starts at 0
    // Q: Why is best practice to omit sizeof knowing that for char it is always 1... all other alloc's need to use sizeof so the inconsistency leads to mistakes
    if ((tmp = realloc(array[i], (len+2)*sizeof(*(array[i])))) == NULL) {
    // if ((tmp = realloc(array[i], len+2)) == NULL) {
      printf("Err: realloc\n");
      return 1;
    }
    array[i] = tmp;
    array[i][len] = (char)chr;
    array[i][len+1] = '\0';
    len++;

    // newline
    if (chr == '\n') {
      len = 0;
      i++;
    }
  }

  if (ferror(f)) {
    printf("Err: read file\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // Verify input
  printf("\nRead:\n-----\n");
  for (i=0; array[i] != NULL; i++) { // array is NULL terminated
    printf("[%d] %s", i+1, array[i]);
    free(array[i]);
  }
  free(array);

  printf("\nDone\n");
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: it makes no sense to realloc one char or one pointer only. It is a bad idea. Memory is cheap so realloc in much larger chunks.

Comment: Whenever you grow the array, `realloc` may be forced to move the entire array to a new memory location if there is no more room in the current memory location. Depending on the size of the array, this can be a very expensive operation. For this reason, growing an array one element at a time is generally not a good idea. You may want to read this question: [What is the ideal growth rate for a dynamically allocated array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100311/what-is-the-ideal-growth-rate-for-a-dynamically-allocated-array)

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation is rather slow, compared to declaring fixed-length arrays as local variables on the stack.

Comment: "You don't ever over-use memory": yes you do. There are overheads in dynamic memory allocation; `realloc()` makes a copy of the data, so you use twice as much memory instantaneously; and pieces of freed memory may never be used again. The idea was idiotic. Especially realloc-ing a character at a time.

Comment: If you have to dynamically grow a contiguous buffer (such as a string), usual practice is to double the size each time.  Once you're done, you can call `realloc` one final time to trim the excess.  The problem with growing it one byte at a time is that it's slow:  Every time you add a byte, you have to copy the entire string.

Comment: @TomKarzes it is a very brave statement. I would say that it would almost never happen on sane system and not very long lines (ie not kChars)

Comment: One better way to do this is to use one dynamically allocated (and reallocated as necessary to enlarge) buffer to read a line and do any initial processing and then copy that line into one newly allocated buffer of custom length for the line. Then you are only doing one allocation per line plus a small number over the whole program to grow the reused buffer to its largest size. That still leaves you with one string copy per line, but it is better than multiple reallocations per line. There are additional options with other characteristics.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  `EOF` is an `int` value that can never match an `int` value from a `char` value from within the file when it's returned from `fgetc()`.  Cramming the value returned from `fgetc()` into a `char` value means your code can either never detect EOF or it can detect EOF because the `char` from the file-that's-*not*-at-EOF happens to contain a value that when truncated to a `char` value and then reexpanded back to an `int` gets sign-extended and now *does* match `EOF`.

Comment: In addition to other suggestions: rather than stuffing all of this into `main`, have something like `struct mystr { size_t cap; size_t len; char *str; };` and then implement functions analogous to `strcpy`, `strcat`, etc. that work on variables of that type.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Your wording was hard to follow but thank you for pointing that out! Most examples online make the same oversight - after all, char is an int type. The following question addresses this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063518/why-does-fgetc-return-int-instead-of-char Thanks again

Comment: @user207421 excellent point on memory usage, thank you. However, I wonder what your definition of an idiot is: someone who doesn't have the same knowledge set as yourself, even if they come here to ask about it? Surely all the things someone like me knows that you do not don't make you as idiotic as it would appear.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I changed the code example to fix that - two very minor changes: the `chr` variable is an `int` and when assigned to a character string, cast to `char` (my understanding is that cast is optional and appeases compiler warnings?)

Comment: @MeSteve Assuming `char` is signed, an assignment without casting from `int` to `char` [is implemenation-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294350/how-assignment-from-int-to-char-works-in-c).  Offhand, I believe on today's twos-complement machines that's usually implemented by just assigning the lowest 8 bits of the `int` to the `char`, but I don't have a reference for that right now, nor do I have one for how the cast affects the assignment.  And since it's "implementation-defined" it's appropriate for a compiler to warn.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `malloc()` or `realloc()` for the first time, he gonna allocated a big chunk of memory. That for future call and not asking for more memory at every single use.

`realloc()` Before everything look behind the allocated block and see if he can extend the block with some free space. if he can't he `malloc()` a new memory space for you.
That a good strategy, but that don't work that well in your case.

The problem here is you `realloc()` multiple pointer.
Every time he `malloc()` a new block for you, he need to copy the previous block in the new one. After that he free your first block and return the new one.
So when you try to `realloc()` multiple pointer, your memory look like a mess and you just create some fragmentation.

Other thing, memory is really cheap now day's, you can allocated much more.
To compare with c++ container implementation, they alloc the space they need * 2, avoiding linear time to increase performance.
You lose a lot of time with all the `realloc()` call's.

Comment: This seems to controvert conventional thinking from the comments above: "When you call malloc() or realloc() for the first time, he gonna allocated a big chunk of memory. That for future call and not asking for more memory at every single use." Are you sure? That would argue the example code doesn't hurt anything. @AndreasWenzel for example

Comment: Or possibly @EricPostpischil can comment on this

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, the issue with growing your dynamically allocated buffer one unit at a time is that you have to call `realloc` every single time, and `realloc` is potentially very expensive as it may involve copying the data currently allocated to a different place in memory, as opposed to "growing" into adjacent memory.

As such, you'd prefer to grow it as few times as possible. While the [ideal growth rate is subject to some discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100311/what-is-the-ideal-growth-rate-for-a-dynamically-allocated-array), we can safely assume it's *not* +1, but closer to x2. This is straightforward. If you know how to grow the array by adding 1, you can multiply the size by 2.

What will also help you is taking this logic out of `main` so that:

- Your code is cleaner and more expressive of your intent without worrying about *how* the work gets done.
- It's easier to test individual pieces of the puzzle to make sure you got the logic right.
- It's easier to repeat.

We'd probably start out with a struct like:

```c
typedef struct mystr {
    size_t len;
    size_t cap;
    char *str;
} mystr_t;
```

And then we'd create a bunch of functions to interact with values of this type.

```c
mystr_t *mystr_new();
void mystr_free(mystr_t *s);
int mystr_full(mystr_t *s);
mystr_t *mystr_from_cstr(const char *cs);
mystr_t *mystr_grow(mystr_t *s);
mystr_t *mystr_cpy(mystr_t *dst, const char *src);
mystr_t *mystr_cat(mystr_t *dst, const char *src);
void mystr_debug(mystr_t *s);
mystr_t *mystr_optimize(mystr_t *s);
```

Now, writing a function to read a line from a file is pretty straightforward:

```c
#define LINE_BUF_SIZE 1024

mystr_t *readline(FILE *fp) {
    if (!fp) return NULL;

    mystr_t *s = mystr_new();
    if (!s) return NULL;

    char buf[LINE_BUF_SIZE];
    while (1) {
        if (!fgets(buf, LINE_BUF_SIZE, fp)) break;

        size_t len = strlen(buf);
        if (buf[len - 1] == '\n') {
            buf[len - 1] = '\0';
            mystr_cat(s, buf);
            break;
        }
        else {
            mystr_cat(s, buf);
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

Now, reading a line from standard input in `main` looks really easy.

```c
int main(void) {
    mystr_t *line = readline(stdin);

    mystr_debug(line);
    mystr_free(line);
}
```