# Can't explain the behavior of this C code snippet

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

See the following code snippet:

```
int len = -2;
char* buff = (char*) malloc(len+4);
if (len > sizeof(buff))
    puts("ERROR!");
else
    puts("OK!");
```

Compiling and running this code on Ubuntu-14.04 (64-bit) using GCC 4.8.2 prints `ERROR`.

I used the following code to print the values of `len` and `sizeof(buf)`:

```
printf("len = %d, size = %lu", len, sizeof(buff));
```

and it prints:

```
len = -2, size = 8
```

Changing the value of `len` has no effect on the value of `sizeof(buff)`, not even for a positive `len`.

If I'm not mistaken, the value `8` is the length of a pointer address on my 64-bit machine, which is constant no matter what I give to `malloc`. If this is it, I have two questions:

**1)** Why is the above `if` statement printing `ERROR`? (Since -2 is not greater than 8 !!)

**2)** Why doesn't the following code print `8`?

```
char array[10];
printf("%lu", sizeof(array));
```

This code prints the length of the array. What's the difference between a `char[]` and `char*` from `malloc`? I know that the first is allocated on the stack, and the latter is dynamically allocated on heap, but in any case they are both pointer addresses of the system memory. I don't understand the different behavior of `sizeof` relative to a `char[]` and `char*` from `malloc`! It seems inconsistent!

Comment: sizeof gives you unsinged value, which you are comparing to signed (negative) value. -2 converted to unsigned value is very large.

Comment: Don't you get a warning for the first code snippet?

Comment: sizeof pointer returns size of a pointer, sizeof array return length of memory occupied by that array.

Comment: @CoolGuy Not with `gcc code.c -o exec`. Though there are additional options that will produce warnings, like `-Wall`.

Comment: @SeyedMohammad , Always compile your code using `-Wall -Wextra` so that you can see warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> if (len > sizeof(buff))
> ```

`sizeof` produces a value of type `size_t`, which is unsigned. When you compare it to a negative `int`, the negative value is promoted to a very large unsigned value. (Unsigned types always use [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), and they trump signed types in binary operations.) So, `-2` is "greater than" anything you could get from `sizeof`.

> Changing the value of len has no effect on the value of sizeof(buff), not even for a positive len.

`sizeof(buff)` is the size of the pointer, not the size of the allocation block. You need to save that in your own variable because C doesn't keep track of allocation sizes.

> What's the difference between a `char[]` and `char*` from `malloc`?

The `char[]` is an array and its size depends on the number of elements in it. The `char*` is a pointer. An array may be used in contexts that take a pointer, but that doesn't make it a pointer per se.

`sizeof( &* array )` or `sizeof( & array[0] )` will both have the same value as `sizeof( ptr )`. The size is a property of the variable, not of the memory block.

Comment: May find [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600991/why-is-a-negative-int-greater-than-unsigned-int/13601259#13601259) informative to this answer. (uptick, btw).

Comment: Thank you. This answer has the best explanation for the second question (difference between `sizeof(array)` and `sizeof(ptr)`).

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with your code?

```
int len = -2;
char* buff = (char*) malloc(len+4); /* don't cast malloc not wrong, but might hide bugs. */
if (len > sizeof(buff)) /* sizeof() is unsigned and len is signed */
    puts("ERROR!");
else
    puts("OK!");
```

you compare a `signed` value with an `unsigned` value, and because of `unsigned` [wrap around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843181/1983495)

```
unsigned int x = -1;
```

then `x > 0` is always true, and almost surely `x > len + 4` which I assume is what you wanted to compare, but surely `x > sizeof(char *)` which is what `x > sizeof(buff)` means in your case.

Also, `sizeof()` gives the size of the type, in your case since `buff` is a pointer, then it's the size of a pointer, make the code work do this

Use `gcc` warnings, it will tell you about the `signed` `unsigned` comparison.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror
```

notice, `-Werror` will treat warnings as errors, aborting compilation when a warning is issued.

If you want to test this, just try it like this

```
int len = -2;
char* buff = (char*) malloc(len+4); /* don't cast malloc not wrong, but might hide bugs. */
if (len > (int)sizeof(buff)) /* sizeof() is unsigned and len is signed */
    puts("ERROR!");
else
    puts("OK!");
```

but remember that `sizieof(buff)` in your machine will be `8` regardless of the value of `len`, you can't compute the length of a `malloc`ed block, you need to store it's length for subsequent use.

If you want, you can create a struct to hold both, the length and the data.

Comment: There is no such thing as "unsigned overflow," only wraparound.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Why is the above if statement printing ERROR? (Since -2 is not
>   greater than 8 !!)

In the condition expression of the if statement

```
if (len > sizeof(buff))
    puts("ERROR!");
```

type `size_t` (usually defined as `unsigned long`) that corresponds to the type of the returned value of operator `sizeof` has higher rank than the type of variable len that has type `int`. So to get the common type len is converted to type `size_t` according to the rules of the **usual arithmetic conversions** and considered as unsigned integral value that is greater than the value returned by sizeof( buff ).

[Note: internal representation of `-2`  can look (I will use only a byte for simplicity) like

```
11111110
```

while of `8` it looks like

```
00001000
```

Thus if to consider the internal representation of `-2` as some unsigned value then it is obvious that `-2` is greater than `8`. - end Note]

From the C Standard (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> 1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause
>   conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to
>   determine a common real type for the operands and result. For the
>   specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
>   domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real
>   type. Unless explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also
>   the corresponding real type of the result, whose type domain is the
>   type domain of the operands if they are the same, and complex
>   otherwise. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions:

And

> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>   unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer
>   conversion rank is converted to the type of the operand with greater
>   rank.
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
>   the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with unsigned integer type.

If you would for example define `len` as having type `long long` then it is posiible that the condition would be equal to false because it could occur that the rank of long long is greater than rank of `size_t` that usually is defined as a typedef for type `unsigned long`

Try the following code snippet

```
long long int len = -2;
char* buff = (char*) malloc(len+4);
if (len > sizeof(buff))
    puts("ERROR!");
else
    puts("OK!");
```

> 2) Why doesn't the following code print 8?

```
char array[10];
printf("%lu", sizeof(array));
```

Operator `sizeof` returns in bytes the size of the object used as operand of the operator. Variable array is defined as an array of 10 elements of type char. In any implementation sizeof( char ) is equal to 1. Thus 10 * sizeof( char ) will result in 10.

Take into account that arrays are not pointers.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. This answer is the most complete explanation for the first question (explaining the behavior of comparing different numerical types).