# Why x is promoted to unsigned int?

Tags: c

Given that code :

```
int main(void) {
    long x = -1;
    if (x < sizeof(x)) {
        printf("OK\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Not Ok\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

`Not Ok`

I have read about usual arithmetic conversions, and from what i understood that if we have a comparison between two operands with different data types, the compiler invokes a data coercion on the operand which is narrower than the other operand, which will convert the the `sizeof(x)` into `unsigned int` to match the other operand, any thoughts?

**Aside question:**
I tried to do casting `size(x)` as `int` in the comparison expression as:

```
if(x < (int) size(x))
```

It prints `Ok`, which I find very strange!

Comment: C is not C++ is not C, tag only one language.

Comment: Explain more about what u wanna do with that code

Comment: The first should rise a warning from your compiler. Why do you think that the second has a strange behavior?

Comment: At the risk of sounding self-serving, [you may find this an interesting read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600991/why-is-a-negative-int-greater-than-unsigned-int)

Comment: To be clear the trap here, as you despite the question seem to have noted yourself, is that the C language does not promote to a wider type when mixing `signed` and `unsigned` expressions of the same size. Despite that this may be unsafe as in the code above. One might argue that this should be done if possible, or issue a compile-time error. That is not how the language is defined however and good compilers issue warnings as a substitute.

Comment: @WhozCraig Why not mark as dupe as that one? That is the answer.

Comment: To expand on some of the above comments, `-1` when converted to an unsigned value is a very large number. It will most definitely not be less than `4` or `8` (which are the common sizes of `long`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, and  size_t has the same size as long as 8 bytes

Comment: @WhozCraig and please, no one's gonna charge you with _self-serving_ :)

Comment: @Bob__ I suppose from the comparison expression `sizeof(x)` is treated as int, and it prints `Not Ok`, and when i tried to cast it to `int`, the program prints `Ok`

Comment: Maybe you should also check out [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) and [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never compare a signed number to an unsigned number. Add a compiler switch to warn you about this.

Here, in your case, `x` will be converted to unsigned, -1 becomes `SIZE_MAX` (the largest number a that `std::size_t` can hold). It is because `sizeof` returns an unsigned number (it returns `std::size_t`, which is unsigned)

The other thing that **could** happen, but don't happen in practice is that if `sizeof(long)>sizeof(std::size_t)` then `sizeof(x)` would be converted to `long`, so your program would print `OK`.